# Tiempo de sesión inactiva y ejecución de consulta SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo algunas dudas con respecto a SQL SERVER,

1.- ¿Hay alguna forma de cerrar una sesión inactiva después de cierto tiempo?, ¿Como hacerlo?

2.- ¿Puedo limitar el tiempo de ejecución de una consulta por usuario o rol?, ¿Como hacerlo?

Gracias!

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Sí se pueden hacer ambas cosas. Pero no es recomendable hacerlo de forma automática. Solo obtendrás reclamos y el servidor igual se cargará de trabajo con nuevas solicitudes de los usuarios que no completaron sus consultas.

Answer (score 1):

Cerrar sesiones inactivas despues de cierto tiempo, adjunto imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El query de la imagen cierra sesiones dormidas de hace 1 hora, puede cambiar los parámetros de HH Hora a DD Días(Según considere) junto con los números -1 por el requerido para cerrar las sesiones inactivas.

En cuanto a "Puedo limitar el tiempo de ejecución de una consulta por usuario o rol?" El siguiente link puede ayudar a limitar el numero de procesadores asignados a una consulta X. Con la finalidad de no copar el resto de procesadores.

https://horacioag.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/limitar-los-recursos-asignados-a-la-ejecucion-de-una-consulta-en-sql-server/

Comment: Por favor el código como texto amigo y no como imagen